# No ground wire doorbell transformer

Tags: transformer, doorbell

Recently got a new video doorbell and noticed that it was flaky, especially at night when the IR was active. Tech support suggested my 16v 10va transformer could be the reason and suggested a 24v/40va model, which I got.

When I opened the panel, I noticed my old transformer has a 3rd green ground wire, but the new one does not have one (see photos). I don't know what to do with that ground wire, so I'm thinking to send this transformer back and get one with a ground wire - I'm obviously not an electrician but I can connect 3 primary wires - but thought I'd check with those more qualified on here first.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is yet another reason [metal boxes are better than plastic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/256189/why-not-use-a-plastic-receptacle-box-for-an-outdoor-outlet/256190#256190). The metal chassis of the transformer is the ground. With a metal box, ground wire from the circuit connected to the box with a proper screw, a metal cover plate attached to the transformer and metal screws connecting the transformer to the cover plate and the cover plate to the box, ground *just works*.

Comment: you don't really need a ground (in this application) anyway, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @dandavis The main point of grounding, by a mile, is *safety*. If this hunk of metal is mounted to a plastic box (and therefore not grounded) an exposed current-carrying wire inside the box could touch the device, electrify the outside (and possibly the low-voltage side as well), and injure someone. Grounding it properly (according to the manufacturer's instructions) is mandatory.

Comment: Yes, it would "work" (operate) without ground, but it would not be safe.

Comment: @nobody isn't the low-voltage side completely made of wraps of insulated wire? If so, how would external current get to the secondary wiring? Such transformers provide a galvanic isolation from the grid, so the only apparent voltage would be +/- 24v, which isn't typically considered dangerous, though with wet hands you _might_ feel it. Most also have thermal one-time fuses, so even a short that melted coil insulation should go open before it goes mains. Given all that, I don't see a safety issue.

Comment: @dandavis Normally? Yes, the windings are insulated. But defects happen. It's important that the metal bulk of the device is grounded so that any faults trip the breaker instead of energizing the case. I've also seen people strip way too much insulation off the low-voltage doorbell wires, so that the extra could touch the case. If the case is grounded, that's no big deal. If it's not grounded (i.e. could be live), doorbell wires touching it could be fatal.

Answer (score 3):

You may not mount this to a plastic junction box. There is a sticker on the device that clearly says "When mounting in a knockout, install on metal box only."

You must mount it to a grounded metal box, or exchange it for one that has a ground wire if you want to mount your doorbell transformer to this plastic box.