# How to deal with twisted switch box

Tags: electrical, switch

I took the cover off a 2-gang light switch box (for painting purposes) and found that the switch on the right wasn't screwed to the box. I figured it would be a simple matter to screw it in, but it appears the reason that it wasn't screwed in is that the box is warped! It's not rectangular. If I screw the switch in, the plate doesn't fit because the whole switch is offset DOWN. (yes, I know, I can rotate the switch — but I can't move it up!) Now, surprisingly (to me), the box is screwed to the stud with three screws from the inside, which as far as I can tell is not up to code. Also, the box is not at the right depth; it's too far into the room and it impinges on the drywall, which I suppose is why it's not rectangular anymore. So — how do I fix this? Am I supposed to remove the whole box and replace it with an old work box? And why might the builder have mounted the box this way? I've pulled the (unanchored) switch out in the photo so you can see.

[image]

Comment: Yet another [reason to use metal boxes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/256189/why-not-use-a-plastic-receptacle-box-for-an-outdoor-outlet/256190#256190)

Comment: Is it askew because it's wedged between framing, or because the drywall opening is off? What's the _cause_ of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is fastened with screws. You can  remove the screws either with a stubbie or right angled screw driver.

Then shift it and screw it back. This process is easier because you can drive the screws at an angle. Dont screw them too tightly.

You can also choose to replace it with a metal one at the same time.

Comment: Or use a Carlon B249B.