# Strain relief and box type when installing external outlet on house with aluminum siding

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor

I am planning on installing a external outlet on the side of my house using a surface mount to reduce the size of the hole I need to make. The easiest option appears to be using a plastic box and in-use cover (like [https://www.amazon.com/Hubbell-Bell-PSB37550GY-Weatherproof-2-Inch-Outlets/dp/B0044FQX0I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0044FQX0I) and [https://www.amazon.com/TayMac-MM410C-Weatherproof-Receptacle-Protector/dp/B001JEPX44](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001JEPX44)).

[Why not use a plastic receptacle box for an outdoor outlet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/256189/why-not-use-a-plastic-receptacle-box-for-an-outdoor-outlet) makes a good case for using a metal enclosure rather than a plastic one. On that question Pelle points out a risk if there were an issue with the grounding in the box potentially causing the box itself (and presumably the siding) to be energized. Is that a valid concern (so plastic would be the better option) or is metal still a better option?

I plan on drilling straight through the siding and into the unfinished basement behind. I would then use a threaded adapter to connect a small piece of PVC to the back of the box and put it through the hole. Then run the cable through the PVC into the house.

Do I need to add some sort of strain relief in the box or just staple it securely inside of the house?

Is it better to mount vertically or horizontally or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: Unless you have one of the few known bad panels, if ground/box becomes energized then the breaker will trip in seconds.  This is what having ground does, metal boxes make better ground paths between ground wire and receptacle, if you forget to connect ground wire to receptacle.